# MINIO - remove a policy from a user

Tags: minio

I have a user which I have applied a policy for using the following format

```
mc admin policy set myminio getonly user=newuser
```

Now, I've added `newuser` into a group, and I want to manage his policies using the group's policies. So adding the user to a group and applying policy on that group is quite straightforward.

Now that he has the group's policy, I want to remove the `getonly` policy that was applied to him personally - how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like there is no direct way to remove policy that have been assigned to a user.

The easiest way that I can think of is deleting the current user and create a new user with the correct policy assigned.

There is another workaround that I have tried.
Assuming I have a user named `test`, this is what I had done to remove the policy from a user:

`mc admin policy set myminio '' user=test`

Answer (score 2):

```
mc policy set none minio/storage
```

**minio** is your bucket and **storage** is the folder.

Comment: `mc policy` if for anonymous access and not for specific users

Answer (score 2):

came here for the same problem and it seems there is a modern solution to this [see: policy detach](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/reference/minio-mc-admin/mc-admin-policy-detach.html#command-mc.admin.policy.detach):

```
mc admin policy detach myminio mypersonalpolicy --user james
```

being

- *myminio* the alias you gave with `mc alias set` to your instance
- *mypersonalpolicy* the policy name you want to remove
- *james* the user you want to remove the policy for